# MIN() aggregate function with some criteria

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have table `Places` with following columns:

```
PlaceId     CityId     Name       Postcode
-----------------------------------------
1           1          Place1     NULL
2           1          Place1     10000
3           2          Place1     10300
4           2          Place2     10500
5           3          Place3     NULL
6           3          Place3     NULL
```

Output I want is:

```
PlaceId     CityId     Name       Postcode
-----------------------------------------
2           1          Place1     10000
3           2          Place1     10300
4           2          Place2     10500
5           3          Place3     NULL
```

So, I need following:

If one city has duplicates over `CityId` and `Name` columns, then I need one row with minimal `PlaceId`. But, if first of two duplicates has NULL in `Postcode` column, and bigger id has some value in same column, then I need second row in output  (example, rows with ids 1 and 2, returned row with id 2). In case that all duplicates has NULL value in column Postcode, then just return minimal `PlaceId` (example, rows with ids 5 and 6, returned row with id 5)

So, column `Postcode` affect in final output

I've tried like this:

```
SELECT 
        MIN(nm.PlaceId) AS PlaceId,
        nm.CityId,
        nm.name,        
        COUNT(*) AS Number
    FROM dbo.Place AS nm
    GROUP BY
        nm.CityId ,
        nm.name
```

I can solve this problem, but solution is not nice, and I am asking for some nice and elegant solution.

Comment: What is the datatype of postcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this ...

```
CREATE TABLE #PLACES
( PlaceId int, CityId int, Name varchar(50), Postcode varchar(50)
)
INSERT INTO #PLACES (PlaceId, CityId, Name)VALUES(1, 1, 'Place1' )
INSERT INTO #PLACES (PlaceId, CityId, Name, Postcode)VALUES(2, 1, 'Place1','10000' )
INSERT INTO #PLACES (PlaceId, CityId, Name, Postcode)VALUES(3, 2, 'Place1' , '10300')
INSERT INTO #PLACES (PlaceId, CityId, Name, Postcode)VALUES(4, 2, 'Place2','10500' )
INSERT INTO #PLACES (PlaceId, CityId, Name)VALUES(5, 3, 'Place3' )
INSERT INTO #PLACES (PlaceId, CityId, Name)VALUES(6, 3, 'Place3' )
```

--- Query

```
;WITH CTE_RESULTS AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CityId, Name ORDER BY Postcode DESC) ROW_NO, PlaceId , CityId, Name, Postcode
    FROM #PLACES
)
SELECT * FROM CTE_RESULTS WHERE ROW_NO=1
```

Comment: Why was this accepted? It's not what the OP describes.

Answer (score 1):

Following query should help for you:

```
;WITH Places as 
(
    select 1 as PlaceId, 1 as CityId, 'Place1' as Name, NULL as Postcode
    UNION ALL 
    select 2, 1, 'Place1', 10000
    UNION ALL 
    select 3, 2, 'Place1', 10300
    UNION ALL 
    select 4, 2, 'Place2', 10300
    UNION ALL 
    select 5, 3, 'Place3', NULL
    UNION ALL 
    select 6, 3, 'Place3', NULL
)
SELECT t2.PlaceId, groups.CityId, groups.Name, t2.Postcode FROM (
    select CityId, Name from Places GROUP BY CityId, Name
    ) groups 
    CROSS APPLY  
    (
        SELECT TOP(1) 
          d2.PlaceId, d2.Postcode, 
          CASE WHEN d2.Postcode IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS RecordPriority 
        FROM Places d2 
        WHERE d2.CityId = groups.CityId AND d2.Name = groups.Name 
        ORDER BY RecordPriority, PlaceId
    ) t2 ;
```

or using `ROW_NUMBER()` with the same `ORDER BY` as above:

```
;WITH Places AS 
(
...
),
OrderedPlaces AS
(
    SELECT *, 
        Rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER
            (PARTITION BY CityId, Name
             ORDER BY CASE WHEN Postcode IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, 
                      PlaceID)
    FROM Places  
)
SELECT PlaceId, CityId, Name, Postcode 
FROM OrderedPlaces
WHERE Rn = 1 ;
```

Comment: You are overcomplicating it with the derived tables (t1 is not needed) but I think this is correct and what the OP wants.

Comment: Thanks @ypercube, really we can simplify query like this: 
 SELECT t2.* FROM (
    select CityId, Name from Places GROUP BY CityId, Name
    ) groups 
    CROSS APPLY  
    (
        SELECT TOP(1) * 
                FROM Places d2 
                WHERE d2.CityId = groups.CityId AND d2.Name = groups.Name 
            ORDER BY CASE WHEN Postcode IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END DESC, PlaceId
    ) t2